# Updating google apps user details

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I want to create a page with a form to update user account details (such as password).
I've already gotten client_id and client_secret for my apps, i also already activated API for my google apps on admin dashboard.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Change password page</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Change Password</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="process.php">
    Username: <br />
    <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
    Old Password: <br />
    <input type="password" name="password" /> <br />
    <br />
    New Password: <br />
    <input type="password" name="newpassword" /> <br />
    Confirm Password: <br />
    <input type="password" name="confirm_newpassword" /> <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Change Password" />

  </form>
</body>
```

from this [link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user), i know that first i have to authenticate my page,

```
//process.php
set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
// authenticate
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(my_client_id);
$client->setClientSecret(my_client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri(urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob);
```

i don't know what i should add to create request to google, i've come to [this link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) but that's not clear enough for me.